# How to hide and show UIViewController button in AppDelegate? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

How to hide and show `UIViewController` button in AppDelegate file in swift?
For exaple: **role="User"** => hide button ; **role="Admin"**  => view button

**Code:**

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!,
              withError error: Error!) {
         //var email = (String)()

        if (error == nil) {


        let givenName = user.profile.name
        let email  = user.profile.email

        let param=["UserName":givenName!,"Email":email!] as Dictionary<String,String>

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string:"http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/EJoC6gB_z")! as URL)

        let session = URLSession.shared
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        //Note : Add the corresponding "Content-Type" and "Accept" header. In this example I had used the application/json.
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: param, options: [])

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
            guard data != nil else {
                print("no data found: \(error)")
                return
            }
            do{
                if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [[String:Any]] {
                    print("Response: \(json)")
                    for user in json {
                        if let role = user["UserRole"] as? String{
                            print(role)

                            if role == "User"{


                                DispatchQueue.main.async (execute: { () -> Void in


                                let  myStoryBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main",bundle:nil)

                                let page=myStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController


                                let  pageNav = UINavigationController(  rootViewController : page )

                                let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate


                                appDelegate.window?.rootViewController=pageNav

                                  [self.vc.apps.isHidden]


                             })





                            } else if role == "NewUser"
                                {
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async (execute: { () -> Void in

                                    let  myStoryBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main",bundle :nil)

                                    let page=myStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ApprovalUser") as! ApprovalUser

                                    let  pageNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController:page)

                                    let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate


                                    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController=pageNav

                                })



                            }else if role == "Admin" {

                                    DispatchQueue.main.async (execute: { () -> Void in



                                    let  myStoryBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main",bundle : nil)

                                    let page=myStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController

                                    let  pageNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController : page)

                                    let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

                                    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController=pageNav

                                })


                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // if you want role of first object only then use
                    // print( json . first?["UserRole"])
                }
            } catch let parseError {
                print(parseError)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please check the answer and reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it with `UserDefaults` or Global Variables. Accessing and modifying UI elements from outside of the parent View Controller is a really bad practice.

I strongly recommend `UserDefaults`, though. In your `AppDelegate`, add this into your code:

```
if role == "User"{
    UserDefaults.standard.set("User", forKey: "role")
    // ... the rest of your code (i.e.: appDelegate.window?.rootViewController=pageNav)
}

else if role == "NewUser"{
     UserDefaults.standard.set("NewUser", forKey: "role")
    // blah, blah, ... rest of your code goes here
} 
else if role == "Admin"{
     UserDefaults.standard.set("Admin", forKey: "role")
}
```

And then in the `viewDidLoad()` of your ViewController:

```
 if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "role") != nil{
      let role = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "role") as? String ?? "User"
      if role == "User" || role == "NewUser" { 
          yourButton.isHidden = true 
          // the role of the user does not allow them to see the button
          }
      else if role == "Admin" { yourButton.isHidden = false }
 }
 else{
      yourButton.isHidden = true 
 }
```

That is the better way in my opinion, rather than accessing a button from another class. Let me know if it helps!

---

### EXPLANATION:

Basically, you just save the value of `role` to `UserDefaults` (aka your app's local memory based on bundle id), and then retrieve it inside your `viewDidLoad()`. There, you're checking the role and hiding/showing the button, depending on the case.

**Note:** This also handles the case of not being able to retrieve the information for some reason, treating the user as a normal "User".

### EDIT:

As per OP's request, I've added multiple user handling. When a new user logs in, just remove those values from `UserDefaults`, then call the entire function. It will look like this:

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!,
              withError error: Error!) {

         //var email = (String)()

         if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "role") != nil{
         UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "role")
         }

        if (error == nil) {
            //...
        }

}
```

Comment: check updated answer... and make yourself more clear please, I don't quite understand your english. if this is not what you want please let me know